# How to plot set from dictionary?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary as follows:
key - user ID
value - set with 2 values {timeTag, amount}

I'm tring to plot one of the users (timeTag vs amount),
but can't figure out how to do so (part of the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdic

# some code adding values, for example:
d = defaultdic(list)
# ... some code
d[userId].append({time, amount})

exampleId = 150
plt.plot(d[exampleId]) # give error
```

how can I plot the userId = 150 (which is the exampleId varable) with time (x axisis) vs amount (y axsis) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `plt.plot` the default arguments you need to pass are the `x` and `y` values as a list. So the last command will change to

```
plt.plot(map(lambda userSet: userSet[0], d[exampleId]), map(lambda userSet: userSet[1], d[exampleId]))
```

The size of the lists retrieved by `map(lambda userSet: userSet[0], d[exampleId])` and `map(lambda userSet: userSet[1], d[exampleId])` should be the same.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Comment: @Boom Because you're using a Set, I see. This does not allow you to get any element from a particular position. Any reason you're using a Set? Otherwise you can change `d[userId].append({time, amount})` to `d[userId].append((time, amount))` and at any place you add elements to `d[userId]` you should use `(time, amount)` instead of `{time, amuont}`.